# MySQL Query to rollup data based on shiftwise for days in month

Tags: mysql

We have a table of content like below,

```
Timestamp           |    Total_Value
2015-06-05 07:14:23  ------------568
2015-06-06 15:14:23  ------------768
2015-06-07 15:14:23  ------------868
2015-06-08 19:47:30  ------------968
2015-06-30 19:47:30  ------------1668
2015-07-01 06:47:30  ------------268
```

shifts starts from Morning 7 AM of current day to next day morning 7 AM. Totally three shifts. So per day data calculation requires data of next day till 7 AM.

```
SELECT DAY(TIMESTAMP) AS DAY, MAX(Total_Value) AS `Total`
FROM Table_NAME
WHERE MONTH(TIMESTAMP) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY DAY(TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY DAY
```

Above query provides the data for individual days properly for the timestamp  between 2015-06-01 00:00:00 to 2015-06-30 23:59:59

But i need the data for a month between 2015-06-01 07:00:00 to 2015-07-01 06:59:59 in the form of

```
Day --------Total_Value
1  ------------0
2  ------------0
3 -------------0 
4 -------------0 
5 ------------568
6  ------------768
7  ------------868
8  ------------968

.
.
.
.
30  ------------1768
```

2) Also need MySQL query to break a day into 3 shifts where hours of shifts are 7AM to 3:30PM, 3:30PM to 11:00PM and 11PM to 7:00AM(next day) and to be grouped for a week.

Please help resolve this issues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract 7 hours from the timestamp to adjust it into the proper day for the shift.

```
SELECT DAY(DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) AS Day, MAX(total_value) AS Total
FROM Table_Name
WHERE MONTH(DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY Day
```

To break it into shifts, use a `CASE` expression to determine the shift

```
SELECT DAY(DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) AS Day, 
        CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:%i') < '07:00' THEN 3
             WHEN DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:%i') < '15:30' THEN 1
             WHEN DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:%i') < '23:00' THEN 2
             ELSE 3
        END AS Shift,
        MAX(total_value) AS Total
FROM Table_Name
WHERE MONTH(DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY Day, Shift
ORDER BY Day, Shift
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar..!! Great..!! Can you please help in sorting out the (2) issue as well. 2) Also need MySQL query to break a day into 3 shifts where hours of shifts are 7AM to 3:30PM, 3:30PM to 11:00PM and 11PM to 7:00AM(next day) and to be grouped for a week.

Comment: My answer has the shift breakdown.

Comment: Why can't you group by week yourself? Use the MySQL `WEEK()` function.

Comment: Yes Barmar. Thanks